# Test if value is an integer in Sass

Tags: sass

How can I test whether a value is an integer in Sass?

I saw some documentation stating there was an `int?` function but I don't think I'm using it correctly. That, or I have misunderstood the documentation.

I am currently doing this, but am getting an error:

```
int?(16)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Chris Eppstein helped me work it out. Pretty easy in hindsight:

```
round($n) == $n
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to let you know, I put Chris' approach in a Sass function. You can find it [on Github](https://github.com/pentzzsolt/sass-is-int) and [on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-is-int).

It does the same thing essentially, but wrapped in a reusable function.

You could use it like this:

```
.selector {
    @if is-int(16) {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Which in this case outputs:

```
.selector {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

- (Bool) unitless(number)

Inspects the unit of the number, returning a boolean indicating if it is unitless.

Examples:

```
  unitless(100) => true

  unitless(100px) => false
```

Parameters:
(Literal) number — The number to inspect

Returns:
(Bool) — Whether or not the number is unitless

Raises:
(ArgumentError) — if number isn’t a number

Comment: I want to check if it is an integer. That means **no decimal places** - a **whole number**.